# How do I go about hiding an element when the user scrolls to a specific point on the page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a sticky navigation bar component and I want to hide it when it meets other elements on the page during scrolling. I understand that I should make a state with an opacity value of 1 which I should pass to the element's style attributes. Then when I scroll to a specific point on the page I should have a function to set the state to 0, but I don't know how exactly to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var note = document.getElementById('stop');
  var screenPosition = note.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (screenPosition.top < 5) {
    console.log("Make Navigation Disappear!")
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1 id="stop" style="color: red;">Make Navigation Disappear!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
<h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
```